How to Remove a Cursor When over a JLabel with an image?

this appears when i hover over with an mouse in a JLabel;
i didn´t find any solution and anyone that had the same problem
behind the JLabel is a JPanel and a JFrame
i´m currently using the java 18 and maven 20 if i´m not wrong.
i´m thinking about removing the entire cursor when it´s over a Image but i don´t know how to....
if anyone can help please leave a comment

I have never seen the cursor change when you hover over a JLabel with an image. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Why do you assume it to be a cursor at all? That yellow box looks more like a tooltip, i.e. when you set an empty string as tooltip text, rather than setting it to null for “no tooltip”.
